# How to send an audio blob (data) file from JavaScript to Java server action in Struts 2?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, file-upload, struts2

We are using Struts2 Application where in I want to send the recorded audio blob file which is in JavaScript, to Java Server (`Action` class). I am using the following Ajax code to send the blob file.

**JavaScript:**

```jsp
  var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload=function(e) {
      if(this.readyState === 4) {
          console.log("Server returned: ",e.target.responseText);
      }
  };
  var fd=new FormData();
  fd.append("filename.wav",blob);
  xhr.open("POST","getAudio",true);
  xhr.send(fd);
```

My method in `Action` class is `getAudio()`. So, since it is a data file, how can I receive it in my method and suggest the appropriate XML configuration to receive the same.

Comment: Call the action url, and pass audio, not getAudio

Comment: If you want to get data file don't send it as blob.

Comment: @AndreaLigios, How to pass audio with the url? and how to receive it?

Comment: @RomanC, is there any way of converting blob to file in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Struts2 you can create xml configuration for the action that will be invoked when you send a file.

```xml
<action name="getAudio" class="com.example.UploadAction" method="upload">
  <result>success.jsp</result>
</action>
```

The class should include a method mapped to the action and a properties for the file and its name.

```java
public class UploadAction extends ActionSupport {
  private String name;
  private File file;

  //getter and setter

  public File getFile() {
    return file;
  }

  public void setFile(File file) {
    this.file = file;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String upload() throws Exception{
      Files.move(file.toPath(),Paths.get("C:\\tmp\\"+name), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
      return SUCCESS;
  }
}
```

Now you should put properties in the form data object

```js
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload=function(e) {
   if(this.readyState === 4) {
       console.log("Server returned: ",e.target.responseText);
   }
};
var fd=new FormData();
fd.append("name", "filename.wav");
fd.append("file", blob);
xhr.open("POST","getAudio",true);
xhr.send(fd);
```

> What is important to know, to be able to deal on the server side with a `FormData` form, is that it is the same as regular form that has been sent with the encoding `multipart/form-data`.

And this is important for Struts2 [`fileUpload` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/file-upload-interceptor.html) to be able to handle it when the action is invoked.

For the further learning I recommend you to read [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/166221/573032).

Comment: Hi Roman, Is there any way of converting audio blob to wav/amr format?